# jQuery: Excluding the elements having id from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to find all divs that the `id` is not included in the array list.

Example:

```
Array: [1, 2, 5]
```

Divs:

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
<div id="4"></div>
<div id="5"></div>
```

I would like to find just the divs that are not included: 3 and 4.

---

I know that I can do:

```
var array = [1, 2, 5];

var stringNot = '';
$.each(array, function (index, element) {
    stringNot.concat('#' + element + ',');
}
stringNot = stringNot.replace(/,\s*$/, ''); // Removing last comma.

$('div').not(stringNot);
```

But, theres a simple way?

Comment: What you're trying to do doesn't really make sense considering you'd need to loop through every single element to find the ones you want. Why not just list the ones you want instead of the ones you don't?

Comment: @XO: He would just need to search through `querySelectorAll('div[id]')`, not all elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to exclude the elements

> Remove elements from the set of matched elements.

Steps:

1. Select all the elements `div`s in this case.
2. Use `join` to join the elements of array using `#,` as the elements in the array are `id`s
3. Add `#` at the start of the joined string, for the first element in the array as `join` will not add it

**Code and Demo**

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 5];

$('div').not('#' + arr.join(',#')).addClass('included');
```

```css
div {
  padding: 5px;
  background: red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.included {
  background: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1">1</div>
<div id="2">2</div>
<div id="3">3</div>
<div id="4">4</div>
<div id="5">5</div>
```

Comment: Wow , that really awesome

Answer (score 3):

Although you have selected your answer, here is how you would do it in Javascript (not jQuery):

```
var idList = [1, 2, 5], // array of ids
    divs = document.querySelectorAll('div'), // select all divs
    notFound;
notFound = [].filter.call(divs, function(div) { // filter into a new array
    return (idList.indexOf((+div.id)) < 0); // where numeric id is not found
});
```

**Snippet**:

```js
var idList = [1, 2, 5], divs = document.querySelectorAll('div'),
    notFound;
notFound = [].filter.call(divs, function(div) {
  return (idList.indexOf((+div.id)) < 0);
});
[].forEach.call(notFound, function(div) {
  div.setAttribute("class", "notfound");
});
```

```css
.notfound { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<div id="1">1</div>
<div id="2">2</div>
<div id="3">3</div>
<div id="4">4</div>
<div id="5">5</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use jQuery? You can try using the `:not()` selector

[jQuery API :not()](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)